# Cannot see shared folder in /mnt/hgfs

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, vmware, lubuntu

I am trying to share a folder between **Lubuntu 13.04** (in VMware player) and Windows 7 64 bit. I followed a tutorial till step 16. I typed a command and saw nothing. I also went into the /mnt/hgfs folder and saw nothing there. How do I fix this ?

http://theholmesoffice.com/how-to-share-folders-between-windows-and-ubuntu-using-vmware-player/

Command -

```
dir /mnt/hgfs
```

---

EXTRAS -

By the way, this is how I actually reached step 16.

Step 12 - `sudo apt-get install hgfsclient`
Step 14 - If it does not work, then follow this tutorial - http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/03/how-to-quickly-install-vmware-tools-in-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/
Step 16 - STUCK !!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I am being offtopic, but I can't help you with that problem.

An alternative way you could share files between the OS'es would be sftp, and mount your linux machine on Windows.

Install : http://winscp.net/eng/index.php

and mount your Linux machines folder username@192.168.x.x:/mnt/hgfs or whatever folder you wish to share.